# How to break the date i.e., 4/7/1995 into this: 4 + 7+ 1+9+9+5 and find the total sum in java?

Tags: java, android

if user select a date from calendar view like 4/7/1995, I want to calculate the sum of given date like this: 4+7+1+9+9+5 = 35, then 3+5=8. where 8 is the main result that will store in a variable for further calculations.
I have tried to store the date in each single variable like this:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 7;
int c = 1;
int d = 9;
int e = 9;
int f = 5;

int result = a+b+c+d+e+f;

system.out.println(result);
```

But this method is not a good practice, and of course user don't want to input the values step by step.
How to get the sum of given date and then split the result into single digit like I mentioned above?

Comment: Convert date to string, take each digit and sum them? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Is this homework? Asking because it should make a little difference to how we answer the question. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Or numerology on a date of birth?

Comment: @OleV.V. NO this not a homework question and YES it is related to numerology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Modulo 9

The final one-digit sum of the digits is the same as the remainder after division by 9. Except that the remainder is 0 when sum is 9. Since all of your digits are non-negatvie and some of them positive, the sum is necessarily strictly positive, so we can safely assume that remainder 0 means sum 9.

```
public static int sumOfDigits(LocalDate date) {
    // I don’t know how to deal with dates from before the Gregorian calendar was introduced
    if (date.isBefore(LocalDate.of(1582, Month.OCTOBER, 15))) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too early");
    }
    int sum = date.getYear() + date.getMonthValue() + date.getDayOfMonth();
    sum %= 9;
    if (sum == 0) {
        sum = 9;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Try it:

```
    System.out.println(sumOfDigits(LocalDate.of(1995, Month.APRIL, 7)));
```

Output is what you had expected:

> 8

If your date picker gives you an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object, convert like this:

```
    LocalDate date = oldfashionedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

If your date picker gives you the date as a string, I see no point in splitting before adding. Either parse it into a `LocalDate` so you have got the date and then proceed as above. Or simply sum the digits, ignoring characters that are not digits:

```
public static int sumOfDigits(String dateString) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char ch : dateString.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        }
    }
    sum %= 9;
    if (sum == 0) {
        sum = 9;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Call for example like this:

```
    System.out.println(sumOfDigits("4/7/1995"));
```

This example gives output 8 as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think that boils down to using the % (modulo) and / (division) operations.

> The modulo operator is used to compute the remainder of an integer division that otherwise lost.

Assuming we have the date entered as `String`, then

- we need to split the String at the occurrences of '/'. This would give you an array containing three elements: day, month, year
- we could transform the `String`s to `int`s. That is beneficial for the next step.
- Day and month have at max 2 digits (1,2... or 01,02,..), a year four. We could split the number by using the / and % operations, e.g. for day 21:

  - sum = 0
  - 21 % 10 = 1, -> add to sum
  - 21 / 10 = 2,
  - 2 % 10 = 2, -> add to sum
  - 2 / 10 =  -> day is processed
- with sum for day, month and year in place you need to sum them up and repeat the process until the result is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you alredy have the date in LocalDate format this could be the solution:

```
//here we get all values of the date. Pretty intuitive.
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonthValue();
int year = date.getYear();
int dateSum = day+month+year;

//here we iterate for number of digits in the dateSum and add.
int result = 0;
while (dateSum > 0) {
    result = result + dateSum % 10;
    dateSum = dateSum / 10;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: You may also exploit the fact that the final one-digit sum is equal to the remainder from division by 9 (except when the sum is 9, the remainder is 0). E.g., 4 + 7 + 1995 = 2006 and 2006 % 9 = 8.

Answer (score 0):

Split Date String by `/`, Find sum of digits of substring till sum is single digit

```
        String dateStr = "4/7/1995";
        String[] dateArr = dateStr.split("/");
        int sum = 0;
        for(String s: dateArr) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
            sum += getSumOfDigits(num);
        }
        // if sum is still two digit value find sumOfDigits
        if(sum > 9) {
            sum = getSumOfDigits(sum);
        }

        System.out.println("final sum:"+sum);
```

Find sum of digits of number

```
private static int getSumOfDigits(int num) {

        int sumOfDigits = 0;
        while(num>10) {
            sumOfDigits+= num%10;
            num = num/10;
        }
        sumOfDigits +=num;
        return sumOfDigits;
    }
```

Input

```
"4/7/1995"
```

Output

```
8
```

Comment: would it make any significant difference if the code was to process each string in the string array using charAt() if the length of string is more than 1? though i find that the way you did it is helpful if the sum later on is still larger than 9, you can reapply the helper method.

Comment: In that case, to find sum of all `charAt()` you need to convert it to int for every char in string

Comment: See the bottom half of my answer for an example of how to do just that. Also @experimentunit1998X